# data.table column/data filtering execution order in R?

Tags: r, data.table

When applying multiple filters, what is the execution order (left-to-right or right-to-left) for a data.table?

For example,

```
dt[,!excludeColumns,with=F][date > as.POSIXct('2013-01-02', 'GMT')][is.na(holiday)]
```

In the above, a data.table is:

1. being excluded few columns
2. filtering the rows for certain date-range
3. filtering the rows for one particular holiday period

Would like to know in which order they get executed? (so that we can put the filter that produces the smallest amount of data first, such that later steps have small data to further operate on, and thus faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should always be left to right!

```
vec <- 1:10
vec[vec>5][1:2]

[1] 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks. Wondering if filtering/excluding the columns first is better or filtering the rows is better?

Comment: I think it shouldn't make a difference, because filtering is applied to the affected columns only (all other columns will be ignored).